# JavaFX 2 XYChart.Series and setOnMouseEntered

Tags: event-handling, javafx

Is it possible to set instance of XYChart.Series to act on setOnMouseEntered? It seems to me that one precondition to make it work would be to implement EventTarget interface. As for JavaFX XYChart.Series I would like to highlight the following data series when cursor touches the yellow line (instance of XYChart.Series):
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/charts/img/line-series.png

To be more precise I would like to do the following but for instance of XYChart.Series not Button:

```
public class Temp {
    /*code removed*/
    Button btn = new Button("Button to touch");
    btn.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Cursor just touched the button!");
        }
    });
    /*code removed*/
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Lookup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) the appropriate nodes and add the event handlers you want to them.

Here is an example.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.Glow;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LineChartSample extends Application {
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    //create the chart
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Number of Month");
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    lineChart.setTitle("Stock Monitoring, 2010");
    XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
    series.setName("My portfolio");
    series.getData().addAll(new XYChart.Data(1, 23),new XYChart.Data(2, 14),new XYChart.Data(3, 15),new XYChart.Data(4, 24),new XYChart.Data(5, 34),new XYChart.Data(6, 36),new XYChart.Data(7, 22),new XYChart.Data(8, 45),new XYChart.Data(9, 43),new XYChart.Data(10, 17),new XYChart.Data(11, 29),new XYChart.Data(12, 25));
    lineChart.getData().add(series);

    // show the scene.
    Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    // make the first series in the chart glow when you mouse over it.
    Node n = lineChart.lookup(".chart-series-line.series0");
    if (n != null && n instanceof Path) {
      final Path path = (Path) n;
      final Glow glow = new Glow(.8);
      path.setEffect(null);
      path.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
          path.setEffect(glow);
        }
      });
      path.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
          path.setEffect(null);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful example. I didn't know that casting techique in terms of JavaFX. Thank you very much!