# Why is the Circle hidden behind the Line?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry

Yes, the title looks like the set up of a joke and yet it isn't.

## The problem

I am writing a program using JavaFX. I add some drawings in a Pane (standard Line, Circle, Rectangle, and so on from `javafx.scene.shape`). I have set a `onMouseEnter()` on some circles to change their color. That works great, except when I place a line like in the image below:

[image: Connector bug]

The circle `A` changes color normally until I add the line `B`. When I hover the circle `A` then, nothing happens.

I figured out by testing that there was a problem when the circle was in the bounding box of the line (if the circle is halfway in the bounding box, the half that is out behaves correctly and the one inside doesn't).

Is it a normal behavious? What can I do to prevent it?

## Partial code

In ConnectorWidget.java:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(...);
circle.setOnMouseEntered(event -> circle.setFill(Color.RED));
circle.setOnMouseExited(event -> circle.setFill(Color.WHITE));
getChildren().add(circle);
```

In TransistorWidget.java:

```
ConnectorWidget base = new ConnectorWidget(...);
getChildren().add(base);
```

In WireWidget:

```
Line line = new Line(...);
getChildren().add(line);
```

A new `TransisorWidget` can be added to the main pane on click.

A new `WireWidget` can be created in the main pane after a click on a `ConnectorWidget` followed by a click on another `ConnectorWidget`.

The rest of the code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/SteeveDroz/tinbap/tree/a98a198ef0a6d62abdb31976204e1d09f2956758) (permalink to the last commit I have when asking the question).

NOTE: To run the code from GitHub, you need [this library](https://github.com/SteeveDroz/phone-book-java).

Comment: The only way I can recreate that is if I call `line.setPickOnBounds(true);`. Did you have that set somewhere?

Comment: Try to revers order of addition of the circle and the line, and you get opposite behavior.

Comment: @James_D I did not.

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE] that recreates this then?

Comment: @talex I can't, the line's coordinates depend on the circle coordinates. The circle must be added first.

Comment: @SteeveDroz I assume he meant reverse in terms of the order in the `getChildren()` list, not first in terms of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it has to do with the fact that one `Node` overlays the other `Node` here.

Imagine that you are using `StackPane` as Layout.Adding first the `Circle` and then the `Line`,if the Line includes some pixels that the Circle already does then some parts of the `Circle` will not be visible.

Here i can imagine **3** possible solutions.

1)If you are using a `Canvas` , choose which is drawn first.The `Circle` or the `Line`?

2)If you are using some kind of Layout ,the you can play with `getChilder.add/addAll` methods.So you add first the `Circle` and then the `Line` as children to the Layout.

3 and better)

Using a `StackPane` you can add the children however you want.Then you can use already existing Node class methods(`toFront(); and toBack();`)

For example imagine that the Line is infront of the Circle, then call Circle.toFront(); and the Circle will come to front.

Comment: Well, I didn't think that would make a difference, thanks for the answer, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You have already marked an answer as correct but I think this leads you in the wrong direction. It may solve your current problem but in general it will not always be possible to organize shapes in such a way.

James_D already metioned what is really going wrong here. This is described in detail in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876083/javafx-pass-mouseevents-through-transparent-node-to-children)

Comment: Actually i didn't even knew about `setPickOnBounds();` :).

Comment: Ok, I'm willing to change my answer to yours if you actually put the answer and not just a link to it.