# How to drag a `Shape` that is below anther `shape` in JavaFX scene graph?

Tags: java, javafx, path, shapes, bezier

I'm writing an educational application using JavaFX in which the user can draw and manipulate Bezier curves `Line`, `QuadCurve`, and `CubicCurve`. These curves should have the capability to be dragged with mouse. I've got two options available:

1- Using classes `Line`, `QuadCurve`, and `CubicCurve`, and then filling them with transparent color, and stroke them with another color, say black. The problem that arises for this option is that the user wants to drag a curve, but sees that another curve is dragged. The reason for this is that the curve that user is going to drag, resides below another one in the scene graph. For example, in the following figure the smaller curve is not capable of dragging, since it is below the larger one in the scene graph.

[image: A curve below another]

2- Using class `javafx.scene.shape.Path`, in which case the problem is that manipulating such a path is a little bit more complicated, since it's composed of some `PathElement`s, and simply manipulating the elements does not change the `Path`, unless we remove an element from its elements property, and add a new one. Therefore I prefer approach 1.

How can I Overcome the problem arising in the first approach?

Thank you in advance for your help. A simplified version of my program code is as follows.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurve;
import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurve;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleForStackOverflow extends Application
{
    double lastMouseX;
    double lastMouseY;
    double lastTranslateX;
    double lastTranslateY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window)
    {
        final double STROKE_WIDTH = 5;

        QuadCurve quad = new QuadCurve(100, 200, 150, 50, 200, 200);
        quad.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        quad.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        quad.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        quad.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            lastMouseX = e.getSceneX();
            lastMouseY = e.getSceneY();
            lastTranslateX = quad.getTranslateX();
            lastTranslateY = quad.getTranslateY();
        });
        quad.setOnMouseDragged(e -> followMouse(quad, e));

        CubicCurve cubic = new CubicCurve(0, 300, 100, 0, 300, 0, 300, 300);
        cubic.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        cubic.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        cubic.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        cubic.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            lastMouseX = e.getSceneX();
            lastMouseY = e.getSceneY();
            lastTranslateX = cubic.getTranslateX();
            lastTranslateY = cubic.getTranslateY();
        });
        cubic.setOnMouseDragged(e -> followMouse(cubic, e));

        Group root = new Group(quad, cubic);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }


    private void followMouse(Node node, MouseEvent e)
    {
        double deltaX = e.getSceneX() - lastMouseX;
        double deltaY = e.getSceneY() - lastMouseY;
        node.setTranslateX(deltaX + lastTranslateX);
        node.setTranslateY(deltaY + lastTranslateY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a transparent color in your first scenario, you should explicitly set the fill color of your curves to null and set pickOnBounds to false. A transparent color will still catch the mouse events but null will not and when pickOnBounds if false the mouse events will be caught only if you are exactly over the colored parts of your shape.

Comment: Thank you very much @mipa. The truth is that a combination of the way you suggested, and using method `setPickOnBounds(false)` that  @JKostikiadis suggested, solved my problem, exactly matching what I needed. I really didn't think that the problem would disappear in such a simple way. Thank both you and @JKostikiadis. I also ask you to edit your answer and mention using method `setPickOnBounds(false)` for anyone else who refers to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Creating the QuadCurve and the CubicCurve using Paths seems to work fine for me. Here is a complete example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.scene.shape.QuadCurveTo;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SampleForStackOverflow extends Application {

    private final double STROKE_WIDTH = 5;

    private double lastMouseX;
    private double lastMouseY;
    private double lastTranslateX;
    private double lastTranslateY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage window) {

        Path quad = initQuadCurve(100, 200, 200, 200, 150, 50);
        Path cubic = initCubicCurve(0, 300, 300, 300, 100, 0, 300, 0);

        Pane root = new Pane(cubic, quad);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    private Path initQuadCurve(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd, int controlX, int controlY) {

        Path curvePath = new Path();
        curvePath.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);

        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(xStart, yStart);

        QuadCurveTo quadTo = new QuadCurveTo();
        quadTo.setControlX(controlX);
        quadTo.setControlY(controlY);
        quadTo.setX(xEnd);
        quadTo.setY(yEnd);

        curvePath.getElements().addAll(moveTo, quadTo);

        curvePath.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            lastMouseX = e.getSceneX();
            lastMouseY = e.getSceneY();
            lastTranslateX = curvePath.getTranslateX();
            lastTranslateY = curvePath.getTranslateY();
        });

        curvePath.setOnMouseDragged(e -> followMouse(curvePath, e));

        return curvePath;
    }

    private Path initCubicCurve(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd, int x1Control, int y1Control, int x2Control,
            int y2Control) {

        Path curvePath = new Path();
        curvePath.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(xStart, yStart);

        CubicCurveTo cubicTo = new CubicCurveTo();
        cubicTo.setControlX1(x1Control);
        cubicTo.setControlY1(y1Control);
        cubicTo.setControlX2(x2Control);
        cubicTo.setControlY2(y2Control);
        cubicTo.setX(xEnd);
        cubicTo.setY(yEnd);

        curvePath.getElements().addAll(moveTo, cubicTo);

        curvePath.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            lastMouseX = e.getSceneX();
            lastMouseY = e.getSceneY();
            lastTranslateX = curvePath.getTranslateX();
            lastTranslateY = curvePath.getTranslateY();
        });

        curvePath.setOnMouseDragged(e -> followMouse(curvePath, e));

        return curvePath;
    }

    private void followMouse(Node node, MouseEvent e) {
        double deltaX = e.getSceneX() - lastMouseX;
        double deltaY = e.getSceneY() - lastMouseY;
        node.setTranslateX(deltaX + lastTranslateX);
        node.setTranslateY(deltaY + lastTranslateY);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

To be honest my first attempt was to call `quad.setPickOnBounds(false);` (and for the cubic as well ) as suggested on both post below :

[Mouse Events get Ignored on the Underlying Layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24607969/mouse-events-get-ignored-on-the-underlying-layer)

[JavaFX Pass MouseEvents through Transparent Node to Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876083/javafx-pass-mouseevents-through-transparent-node-to-children)

But its not working or I miss something, but if creating the path by yourself works find its unnecessary to complicate thing more. In any case I recommend to have a look on the links if you want to follow the first approach. In case you are going to follow the second approach manipulating the paths is not going to be very difficult in my opinion.