# Mouse Events for Unfocused JavaFX Stage

Tags: javafx

[Always On Top, Undecorated Navigation with Decorated Stage Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Svp.png)

I'd like to position Stage 1 always on top to act as a navigation bar while I open stages below, but also be able to interact with Stage 2 while Stage 1 has focus. Is this possible?

A [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879652) suggested using setPickOnBounds(), but applying this to both stages doesn't seem right. At the moment it's taking two or more clicks (with one click to switch focus) In order to interact with Stage 2.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901224/12915080) also seemed similar, but hoping JNI code isn't required. I don't have the option to pull in another library at the moment.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: From your picture I don’t understand why you cannot just put everything in a single stage.

Comment: @kleopatra working on minimal example.

Comment: @jewelsea It's a multi-monitor application that allows the user to move the secondary window to other displays.